# Qt C++ Menubar not shown on Windows but on Mac

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm quite new to Qt and i'm having a problem with a Menubar. I just copied the example code from [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qml-qtquick-controls1-menu.html#details) and added a surrounding MenuBar-Tag

```
MenuBar{
Menu {
title: "Edit"

MenuItem {
    text: "Cut"
    shortcut: "Ctrl+X"
    onTriggered: console.log("test")
}

MenuItem {
    text: "Copy"
    shortcut: "Ctrl+C"
    onTriggered: console.log("test")
}

MenuItem {
    text: "Paste"
    shortcut: "Ctrl+V"
    onTriggered: console.log("test")
}

MenuSeparator { }

Menu {
    title: "More Stuff"

    MenuItem {
        text: "Do Nothing"
    }
}
}
}
```

On Mac does it work properly but on Windows  I can't see any menu. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add menu bar to a window, you need to set `menuBar` property value. See [this page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qml-qtquick-controls1-applicationwindow.html#menuBar-prop):

```
ApplicationWindow {
  id: window
  menuBar: MenuBar {
    Menu { MenuItem {...} }
    Menu { MenuItem {...} }
  }
}
```

May be it doesn't matter on Mac because `QMenuBar` works differently on Mac and is automatically attached to windows.

Comment: thank you. it's working but only inside of an ApplicationWindow{}-tag,  but my main.qml's parent element is a Rectangle{} and after adding your code to my rectangle{} i get the error: Cannot asign to non-existing property "menuBar" and my application does only start with a white empty window :/

Comment: It seems that Rectangle control doesn't support menu bars. Make ApplicationWindow your top window and insert main Rectangle in it as the central widget.